# AngularJs - ng-repeat not displaying data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can someone advise why the following is not working.

Controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module("shop")
    .controller("CartSummaryController", CartSummaryController);

function CartSummaryController($scope, cart) {

    $scope.cartData = cart.getProducts();

    console.log($scope.cartData);

    $scope.total = function () {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cartData.length; i++) {
            total += ($scope.cartData[i].price * $scope.cartData[i].count);
        }
        return total;
    }

    $scope.remove = function (id) {
        cart.removeProduct(id);
    }


}

})();
```

Html:

### Your Cart

```
<div ng-show="cartData.length == 0">
    There are no products in your shopping cart.
</div>

<div ng-hide="cartData.length == 0">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th class="text-right">Price</th>
                <th class="text-right">Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in cartData">
            <td>{{item.count}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.price | currency}}</td>
            <td>blah</td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>

</div>
```

Object printed to console:

Object
count
:
1
id
:
"1"
name
:
"item #1"
price
:
"100.00"

Furthermore, is there a way to debug the ng-repeat?

Comment: Please use `console.log(angular.toJson($scope.cartData));`, and post the output.

Comment: [{"count":1,"id":"1","price":"100.00","name":"item #1"}]

Comment: Did you give your ng-app and ng-controller names correct? Can you show rest of HTML page as well?

Comment: What happens when you add `{{ cartData }}` to the template? If it doesn't display anything, the problem is in code you don't show. Try posting a complete example in a plunkr.

Comment: @JBNizet when i print {{ cartData }} the object prints to the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The label `</table>` should go after the label `</tbody>`

Comment: Excellent, I knew it would be something as simple as that. Thanks dude!

Comment: @ClarkySmiverz77 You're welcome and I'm glad it has been solved.